# Create a vector map and make user move through with three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I want to create several way maps that look [like this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8tqshwffwldi4oa/lines.jpg), each map is use for each level of my game, user (the camera) will move toward and backward through a line when holding the up or down arrow keys.

Please tell me the strategy to build custom vectors like this and make user move thought this vectors only using three.js, (he/she can not go to anywhere his/her want to)

Comment: [This example](http://threejs.org/examples/#misc_controls_path) has the camera following a path

Comment: This example using PathControls for the movement, but look like it does not has config to support free movement by using the keyboard. Thanks for your comment because i found the spline (Math) that can be used to create movement vectors, then i need to moving the camera go through this vector. Waiting for more advises.